# How do I select no items with an updateSelectinput in shiny?

Tags: shiny

I have a `selectizeInput` and some action links to make it easier to select certain subgroups.  I'd like to have one action link which deselects all values (to make it easier to choose just one item for example -- deselect them all and then the user picks one).  The code:

```
updateSelectizeInput(session, "selectizeList", selected = NULL)
```

doesn't work, which is by design as the help for `updateSelectizeInput` (http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSelectInput.html) states:

> Any arguments with NULL values will be ignored; they will not result
>   in any changes to the input object on the client.

Given that this is a feature, how can I unselect all values?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 7):

I did

```
updateSelectInput(session, "selectizeList", selected = '')
```

and it seems to be working for me

Comment: this works.. side note: if you want to also cleanup choices you need to set `choices = character(0)`

Answer (score -3):

Try the following:

```
updateSelectInput(session, "selectizeList", selected = .)
```

Comment: Nope.  `Warning: Error in updateSelectInput: object '.' not found`